# onEachFeature bindPopup

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I am trying to use Mapbox to display my maps.

a) I need to bind a popup on each polygon within a Tileset. I have done it in Leaflet using the `onEachFeature` function. The data should come from the Tileset's vector fields. Please focus on the Tileset as the source of information.

b) I also need to label the polygons using a field within the Tileset.

I simple script will do me just fine. This is where I am right now

```
<script>
        L.mapbox.accessToken = 'Token';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map')
.setView([-1.3328338, 36.8831222], 17)
.addLayer(L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/map/Tileset'));

var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer({
type: 'vector',
features: [{
type: 'Feature',

    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {

        var content = '<a "href="PlotMainDetails.apx?"' + feature.properties.plotno_1 + '" </a>"';
        layer.bindPopup(content);

        
    },
}]
})
.addTo(map);
```

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code.

Comment: Please ask only One question per Question.